# Как правильно сортировать таблицу в DataGrid C# WPF SQLite

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть таблица в БД, я вношу данные этой таблицы в datagrid моей программы, отображаю.Но теперь хочу сделать сортировку, например по дате(2 услвия - С какого и ПО какое число выводить записи). Как лучше всего поступить сортировать уже существующую таблицу в самом datagrid(как это можно реализовать в таком случае?) или создавать новые запросы SQL к БД для вывода уже выборки из таблицы(Если так то реализовать более чем 2 условия будет(по крайней мере как я могу) много кода, слишком будет)

Структура обработчика события щелчка по кнопке "отсортировать". Только теперь какие функции позволят добиться результата, вот в чем вопрос.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowDataBase("Пациенты");

        if ((bool)SortFromCheckBox.IsChecked)
        {
            //Убрать все записи младше опр-ой пользователем даты
        }
        if ((bool)SortUntilCheckBox.IsChecked)
        {
            //Убрать все записи старше опр-ой пользователем даты
        }
        if ((bool)SortByClientCheckBox.IsChecked)
        {
            //Убрать все записи, где в поле Имя нет имени заданного пользователем
        }
        if ((bool)SortByDoctorCheckBox.IsChecked)
        {
            //Убрать все записи, где в поле Доктор нет доктора заданного пользователем
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй `CollectionViewSource` как источник данных для `DataGrid`. 
Самому `CollectionViewSource` в `Source` подавай данные, полученные из базы, а сортировку задавай через `SortDescriptions`.

Comment: программно самый простой вариант: смотри статический метод в CollectionViewSource https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview(v=vs.110).aspx
через xaml смотри https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Даже напугался немного, мне кажется это таким сложным делом, пытаюсь сейчас понять. Спасибо за ссылки :)

Comment: Понял, что полный провал в знаниях.Что можно почитать, чтобы разобраться, начиная с азов?